# Heading to another page in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, head

I was curious to know if there was another way than using javascript to make php go to another page ?

Because head only works when it is the first function to be called, so I resorted to javascript to go to another page. But php must have a similar function no ?

```
    <?php session_start();
      session_destroy();
      echo '<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
 window.location="home.php";
//-->
</script>';



?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mistake.

```
header('Location: some_location.php');
```

Needs to be the first things that's being output, meaning, if you echo anything before this, it wont work, other wise it will work.

So just:

```
header('Location: some_location.php');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<?php 
    header('Location: error.php');
?>
```

For more info: [php manual header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Cleber.

Comment: To be precise: the location header shall point to an absolute URI, cf http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the header of your HTTP Response with the function header in php

http://www.php.net/manual/function.header.php

```
<?php
header("Location: home.php")
?>
```

Also you can add a particular header used by the browser.
for example if your page has moved permanently, you can use:

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header("Location: home.php");
?>
```

You can see more information about redirection on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  You can use a "meta redirect":

http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm

For example:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://webdesign.about.com/">`